# Break url in tabular

Tags: tables, line-breaking, urls

How can I break `hyperref` URLs in a `tabular` environment. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}

\url{http://www.avery/long/url?zz/very/very/long/this/should/break/very/long/long.html}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
   A long url &
\url{http://www.avery/long/url?zz/very/very/long/this/should/break/very/long/long.html}

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

The first one breaks, the second one doesn't. The output looks like:

[image: url]

I am using `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `p{10.0cm}` column specification, which require a length.  This makes the column able to have line breaks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\url{http://www.avery/long/url?zz/very/very/long/this/should/break/very/long/long.html}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l p{10.0cm}}
   A long url &
\url{http://www.avery/long/url?zz/very/very/long/this/should/break/very/long/long.html}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `l` column specification has no control over the column width and therefore doesn't break the URL properly. Either fix the column using a `p{<len>}` column specification (where `<len>` is a known TeX length), or use the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to fix the table width to some maximum:

[image: Tabularx with URL]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
%\usepackage{breakurl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/breakurl

\begin{document}

\noindent\url{http://www.avery/long/url?zz/very/very/long/this/should/break/very/long/long.html}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
   A long url & \url{http://www.avery/long/url?zz/very/very/long/this/should/break/very/long/long.html}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}​
```

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) loads the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) by default, which does a good job of breaking URLs.