# Combine multi-line cell and \url

Tags: tables, urls

I have a bigger table in my document, including several urls. I made them active with the `\url{...}`-command, and now I wanted to make them multi-line-cells by using the `\specialcell{..\\..}`-command, which is defined as

```
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```

But this combination (`\specialcell{\url{a\\b}}`) does not result in a multi-line url, but instead in the url `a\\b`. Is there another way to get a multi-line url in a table cell?

Comment: Try to use column type `p{<width>}, than `url` will break similarly as in text (with the same problems). Other options is use `hyperref` package: `\hyperref[label_name]{''link text''}` where you can more freely write you label (name of link).

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example for `p{<width>}`?

Comment: It will be better that you provide Minimal Working Example (MWE), which will show your problem. It should contain `\documentclass{...} <relevant packages and newcomand definitions> \begin{document} <your table with \url> \end{document}. I will then try to help you.

Comment: Found one here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42041/break-url-in-tabular?rq=1

Comment: Then I suggest to close your question as duplicate to given link.